Financial based equation for Cash Flow analysis on Annuity ( Sequences and Series Analysis)
I have a particular Annuity type of question.
I am familiar with all the Cash Flow type of equations such as Present Value, Future Value for compound interest, and for  Annuities and Mortgages etc.
BUT it seems those equations do not apply in my particular use case.
So here is the question, lets say I have : $$ $50,000 $$
as Principal in an Annuity which pays out $600 a month.
This principal is invested for 1 year, at 5.50% per year compounded annually.
Now if I was to just use simple interest = 50000 * 0.055 = 2750
Then one can possible say that the amount at the end of the year would be:
50000 + 2750 - (12*600) =52750 - 7200 = 45500
SO what I just did, I know is simplistic.
I know how the Annuity Present Value, formula are derived from Sequences and Series.
But that derivation dependent on a period of time over which all of the principal used up  totally.
SO, is there any equation to calculate the total for my use case above.
This use case is very important, because if one keeps choosing an annual interest over 1 year and then have to re-invest for another one year, how do we determine the total value of the Annuity at the end of a year.
Hope someone can help!

It is not clear for me what your question is.

Hi @callculus42, let me explain. In this annuity problem, a certain amount is taken out each month, so each month your total amount goes down  by 600 dollars, but you are also getting interest, so how much will you have at the end of 1 year! that is the question.
